# Create a RibbonControl in code-behind

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint, ribbonx

I'm working on a PowerPoint Add-In project.

I'm trying to create a RibbonToggleButton in code-behind but I can't do it the way I thought,

```
RibbonToggleButton toggleButton = new RibbonToggleButton();
```

Is it possible to create RibbonControls in code-behind and not the RibbonDesigner or RibbonXML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbontogglebutton.aspx):

> You can create a `RibbonToggleButton` at
>   run time by using the
>   `CreateRibbonToggleButton` method of the
>   [`RibbonFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbonfactory.aspx) object.

It looks like you get at the `RibbonFactory` via the [`RibbonBase.Factory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbonbase.factory.aspx) property.

You may also want to look through [this walk-through](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608628.aspx).